# Составить список ключей из словаря при совпадении ключа и значения

Tags: python

Мне надо сравнить два  параметра и если они одинаковые, программа должна как-бы думать, если верно, `true`. Но при этом она не должна что-нибудь выдавать. Программу надо выразить через `def`. Как раз это у меня не получаетcя.

```
hauptstädte = {

    'Baden-Württemberg':'Stuttgart' ,
    'Bayern':'München' ,
    'Berlin':'Berlin' ,
    'Brandenburg':'Potsdam' ,
    'Bremen':'Bremen' ,
    'Hamburg':'Hamburg' ,
    'Hessen':'Wiesbaden' ,
    'Mecklenburg-Vorpommern':'Schwerin' ,
    'Niedersachsen':'Hannover' ,
    'Nordrhein-Westfalen':'Düsseldorf' ,
    'Rheinland-Pfalz': 'Mainz' ,
    'Saarland': 'Saarbrücken' ,
    'Sachsen': 'Dresden' ,
    'Sachsen-Anhalt':'Magdeburg' ,
    'Schleswig-Holstein':'Kiel' ,
    'Thüringen':'Erfurt'
}


def Stadtstaaten(hauptstädte):
    for Stadtstaaten in hauptstädte.items():
        l = hauptstädte[0] == hauptstädte[1]

        return Ergebnis
```

Вот задание:

Напишите функцию city-states (), которая возвращает все федеративные государства в виде списка, где имя капитала равно имени состояния. Используйте словарь из упражнения 3.3.1.

Примечание. Если вы вызываете метод .keys () (например, Capitals.keys (), вы можете получить ключи словаря, обработав ключ напрямую с помощью цикла for.

Comment: Вставьте в вопрос код текстом, а не ссылкой. Опишите внятно вашу проблему, что не получается.

Comment: Условие задачи переведено скорее всего авто-переводчиком. Это так?

Comment: `Имя капитала равно имени состояния`? Столица=Штат?

Comment: @vp_arth Скорее всего так: ключ :"федеральная земля", значение: "Столица". Если они совпадают, например: 'Bremen':'Bremen', то ключ занести в список, список в конце вернуть. Так в кривом переводе задачи, а у ТС в описании что-то не совсем понятное.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы найти ключи в словаре, которые равны соответствующим значениям:

```
city_states = [state for state, capital in german_states.items()
               if state == capital]
```

Чтобы найти ключи, которые в значениях присутствуют (не обязательно в той же паре ключ-значение):

```
>>> german_states.keys() & german_states.values()
{'Hamburg', 'Berlin', 'Bremen'}
```

Это показывает, какие земли имеют то же название, что и какие-нибудь столицы земель. В данном случае оба метода одинаковые строки возвращают (как список и set соответственно).

В общем случае может быть разница между этими методами:

```
>>> d = {1: 2, 2: 1}
>>> [k for k, v in d.items() if k == v]
[]
>>> d.keys() & d.values()
{1, 2}
```